# Difficulty in building neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm performing fault analysis on induction motor considering sag and swell. We have a set of data for all types of sag and swell and our analysis includes healthy/balanced supply.

What are the inputs, samples and targets to be considered in building neural networks and how to train the network in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matlab installed neural network toolbox, here are plenty of [examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/) that you can learn from.